# any new algorithm for fuzzy hyperbox pruning?(Fuzzy min max Neural network)

Tags: java, neural-network, data-mining, fuzzy, pruning

I am working on project Fuzzy Min Max Neural network(classification).
there is a requirement from client to use two or more pruning algorithm to prune hyperbox?
Hyperbox is a n Dimensional box in which each dimension of box represent a attribute of data set( m Using WBC data set).

link for the IEEE Paper is given below:
ftp://ftp.inf.ufrgs.br/pub/SIA/refer%EAncias/fuzzy%20min%20max%20classifier.pdf

And m searching on internet but not able find a single solution to prune hyperbox(except AJ solution) .
can anyone suggest me any solution or your own idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the confidence factor for each hyperbox and then prune the hyperbox which is having confidence factor lower than user defined threshold value.